# Buildfire: saving to datastore produces error

Tags: buildfire

I am trying to save data to the datastore.
Code that previously worked  is now producing an error:
datastore POST Error with URL: https://datastore.buildfire.com/plugin/save/7490bbd8-3a4e-11e9-8fc5-06e43182e96c/myPlugin2/1553485520785-09569307518853045/contactInfo/"

And

POST https://datastore.buildfire.com/plugin/save/7490bbd8-3a4e-11e9-8fc5-06e43182e96c/myPlugin2/1553485520785-09569307518853045/contactInfo/ 403 (Forbidden)

I am not sure if I have change something to cause this or something has change at the datastore end?

To test it I went back to some simple code (see below) and got the same result.

To test it I went back to some simple code (see below) and got the same result.

function saveData() {
        buildfire.datastore.save({name: "The Name", tel: "123456789"}, 'contactInfo', function (err, data) {
            if (err)
                console.log('there was a problem saving your data');
            else
                console.log('your data has saved successfully');
        });
    }

Expect data to be saved to datastore.

Result:
"datastore POST Error with URL: https://datastore.buildfire.com/plugin/save/7490bbd8-3a4e-11e9-8fc5-06e43182e96c/myPlugin2/1553485520785-09569307518853045/contactInfo/"

and

datastore POST Result:  403 https://datastore.buildfire.com/plugin/save/7490bbd8-3a4e-11e9-8fc5-06e43182e96c/myPlugin2/1553485520785-09569307518853045/contactInfo/

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and tested it and it worked just fine for me. However, here are a few possible answers:

1. If you are trying to save data on the Widget side of the plugin it will fail. Since the Datastore is read-only on the widget side
2. If you're trying to serialize an object that has functions
3. If you've changed your AppID or DataStoreKey in the settings tab

Hope this helps

Comment: I am trying to save data from control. I am trying to save plain text and I have not changed the AppID or DataStoreKey. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: Have you tried just creating a brand new plugin and just dumping your code in it for a sanity check? Also, are you getting the error in the plugin tester or on the Control Panel?

Comment: I ended up changing the app id to one from another dev account and it now works.